# How does the "return" keyword return a non-specified value when the return type is not specified? [Swift Playground]

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Swift Playground provided the following code. The code's return causes the image placed upon touch to be spaced out. How does the function work when the return value is not specified and the return keyword is not followed with anything? Is there a default return value and type when nothing is not specified? Also when I tried out this code in Swift(the actual prog language on mac), the Touch type does not exist. Do I need to import a specific library for Swift Playground's code to work in Swift?

```
func addImage(touch: Touch) {
    if touch.previousPlaceDistance < 50 {
        return
    }

    let graphic = Graphic(image: ⭐️)
    scene.place(graphic, at: touch.position)
}
```

Comment: touch does not exist because you don't tap screens on a mac, only on an iphone or ipad

Comment: What's the point of learning to use the Touch class when I won't be able to use it when creating an actual app? 

Comment: Well, you can use it for iOS, not OSx

Answer (score 2):

The `return` here simply short-circuits the method so that it stops if the `previousPlaceDistance` is less than 50. It doesn't have to return a value; in fact, it *can't* return a value if no return type was specified for the function.

It is precisely this kind of short-circuiting where `guard` would be ideal, i.e.

```
guard touch.previousPlaceDistance >= 50 else {
    return
}
```

Comment: Thx for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

This function does not need to return anything in the function definition. So simply calling `return` in enough in this case.

For example a function that need to return a string will look like this. In this case, you will have to return a string in your `return` statement. Functions without that `-> ...` line means that it returns nothing, or the so called `void`

```
func addImage(touch: Touch) -> String {
    if touch.previousPlaceDistance < 50 {
        return ""
    }
    ...
}
```

For your second part of question, `Touch` is a class written in swift to provide some convenience when you playing around with swift playgound. However it does not exist in default swift library. A similar library can be `UITouch` and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch) is apple's document on that.

Comment: Thx!! What's the point of learning to use the Touch class when I won't be able to use it when creating an actual app? 

Comment: @M.AB I think as Apple mentioned, *Learn serious code on your iPad. In a seriously fun way.*. Swift playground is just trying to introduce you that coding in swift is funny and easy. However, even you cannot use the `Touch` class directly in swift, the default `UITouch` is more powerful than `Touch` for sure

Answer (score 0):

Where no explicit return type is given [a function or method returns Void](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)

> The type of this function is () -> Void, or “a function that has no
>   parameters, and returns Void.”

The return of Void can be performed explicitly by writing `return` as in the function that you supply or implicitly (i.e. return is not written anywhere within the function or method).